# Can CNN detect text in arbitrary position of image?

Tags: classification, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, computer-vision, optical-character-recognition

My task is that: there are some text in some position (left, right, top, bottom center, etc) of an images. The style (include size, orientation, font, etc) of text is arbitrary and the content length is arbitrary too.

I want train a classifier to tell whether there is text on the image? The classifier do not need to tell the location of the text.

Can I do that by using convolutional neural network? Is it feasible in principle?

Answer (score 3):

The task is often referred as *Text Detection*. Convolutional neural networks are one of the most suited models for that task.

Some ideas:

- [A curated list of resources dedicated to scene text localization and recognition](https://web.archive.org/web/20170207033948/https://github.com/chongyangtao/Awesome-Scene-Text-Recognition)
- Ye, Qixiang, and David Doermann. "Text detection and recognition in imagery: A survey." IEEE transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence 37, no. 7 (2015): 1480-1500. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=16602446679055861287&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6945320/ ; http://sci-hub.cc/10.1109/TPAMI.2014.2366765